# Callback function with this.setState not working in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js and I have the following functions:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    //Retrieves cart from storage
    let self = this
    this.updateCart(Store.getCart(), self)


    ...
}


updateCart = (cart, self) => {
    var tempCartCost = 0;
    var tempCartItems = 0;
    var {deliveryCost} = this.state;

    if (cart.length > 0) {
      cart.forEach(item => {
        tempCartCost = tempCartCost + (item.quantity * item.price)
        tempCartItems = tempCartItems + (item.quantity)
      })
    } else {
      this.setStep(1) //Falls back to initial page
    }

    var newState = {
      cartCost: tempCartCost,
      authorizedPrice: Math.ceil((tempCartCost + deliveryCost) * 1.1),
      shoppingCart: cart,
      cartItems: tempCartItems
    }

    self ? this.setState(newState) : this.setState(newState)

    (cart !== Store.getCart()) && Store.setCart(cart)

  }
```

Now, the code is working. However, I do not understand why. I thought that if I removed `let self = this` and changed `self ? this.setState(newState) : this.setState(newState)` to simply `this.setState(newState)` it would work. But it doesn't.

Can anyone explain me what's going on here? ‍♀️

Comment: it have to work without self, does it throwing some error without self? how are you saying its not working?

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, there is something wrong with your code. You are never doing something like `setstate(newState, callback)`.

Comment: @ArunKumar If I change `self ? this.setState(newState) : this.setState(newState)` to simply `this.setState(newState)` it throws me the error attached in [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/qGjOjgg).

I really don't understand how this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without passing self, and do setState by `this.setState({ newState )}`,
because since we are using `this` there is actually no point of accessing `self`.